# With c.sort() TypeError: unorderable types: Node() < Node()

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, huffman-code

I'm using python 3.5 and I have a list c.

When I'm trying to do

```
c.sort() ## sort the nodes by count, using the __cmp__ function defined in the node class
```

I get the error `TypeError: unorderable types: Node() < Node()`

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python3 you must to explicitly define all comparison operators for a class in order to make it sortable: ==, !=, <, <=, > and >=:

```
class Node:
    # ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # ...

    # same for the other operators
```

Clearly this is redundant, you can reduce the copy/paste by doing any of the following.

1. Make the class a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), in which case the instances would be compared lexicographically.
2. Define a single comparison operator and decorate the class with [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)